# Azure Artifacts download failure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, azure-artifacts

I'm trying to create Azure DevOps Pipeline template as to download wheel file from Azure Artifacts. This method is working successfully when we are trying to give version like `version: 'latest'` if we give specific version like `version: '1.0.0'` then it failed with error. As per Microsoft Documentation for [DownloadPackage@1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/download-package-v1?view=azure-pipelines) I have given everything as expected. But not sure what is happening internally.

Could anyone help me out what is happening here

```yaml
  - task: DownloadPackage@1
    displayName: "[DOWNLOAD] - ${{ parameters.packageName }}-${{ parameters.packageVersion }}"
    inputs:
      packageType: pypi
      feed: "${{ parameters.feedName }}"
      view: ${{ parameters.viewName }}
      definition: ${{ parameters.packageName }}
      version: ${{ parameters.packageVersion }}
      downloadPath: $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)
```

**Error:**

> ##[error]Fetching package metadata using url https://feeds.dev.azure.com/OrganizationName/_apis/Packaging/Feeds/FeedName%40View/Packages/PackageID/Versions/1.0.0 failed with error Error: 404: null
> at D:\a_tasks\DownloadPackage_randomId\1.216.0\package.js:67:31
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

Comment: Double check if the feed is scoped to the organization versus the project. If it's a project scoped feed, you need to make sure the value for `feed` is in the format `projectID/FeedID`.

Comment: @tj-cappelletti it is organisation scoped and it is released till Release View. I can download from all 3 views if I specify latest. It fails only when I give specific version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually It turns to be version parameter does not accept tailing zeros, if we give version manually.

i.e: for the version 1.0.0 we should be giving 1 instead 1.0.0 then it is working as expected.